# User privilege for index creation / drop in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I know that there is GRANT privilege in PostgreSQL which grants permission to a particular user to assign privilege on various operations .Is there a way to GRANT CREATE/DROP privilege on indexes without granting ALTER/CREATE/DROP privilege for COLUMNS+TABLE+DB

Comment: _did you read this [Postgres Documentaion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html)_ ?

Comment: I have a scenario like this :
Table : xTable
Columns : col1, col2, col3
Index on col1 is indexCol1

Now I have revoked the user from altering xTable, col1, col2, col3. 
So what is the query to grant CREATE / DROP on indexCol1 ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114735/postgres-how-can-i-allow-index-creation-but-no-table-mutations-or-table-drops-b

Answer (score -2):

the syntax is:

```
GRANT { { SELECT | INSERT | DELETE | UPDATE } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { SEQUENCE sequence_name [, ...]| ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

e.g.

```
GRANT SELECT ON serialid_index TO mywebsuser;
```

The permissions are granted separately for tables, etc.